# Tree diagram for Bayes rule with three events

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian, visualization

While learning Bayes' Rule, I found the tree diagram visualization very helpful when finding $P(B|A)P(A)$ etc. when solving for $P(A|B)$.

The tree diagrams I used so far look like this:

[image]

[*Source*](https://images.template.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/02094732/Sample-Tree-Diagram-of-Bayes-Theorem-Diagram.pdf)

This works well so far, but now I need to use Bayes Theorem for three events, that is, I need $P(A|C, B)$, and for that, it'd be helpful to find $P(C|A, B)P(A|B)$ using the formula

$$
P(A|C, B) = \frac{P(C|A,B)P(A|B)}{P(C|B)}
$$

---

I wasn't able to find examples online and I wasn't able to derive it myself: How would a tree diagram help me in the case of three events ? Is it even valid to tack on another level after event $B$? How do they multiply together?

[image]

Comment: It looks fine. Nice.

Comment: I have never seen a comma used in a conditional probability expression in this way.  Perhaps you are trying to find $P(C| A \cap B)$ and similar?  Yes, tree diagrams can have three branches.  If the probability at the end of the two-branch tree is the intersection of two events, say $P(A \cap B)$, then the end of the three-branch tree should typically signify $P(A \cap B \cap C)$, or the intersection of whatever three events are represented at each node.

Comment: What you showed looks reasonable, but the real question is to check how you applied the diagram for your purposes, and a practical example... If you would like to add it, I think you could receive more feedback

Comment: @JeffreyHarkness the comma notation is quite common and has exactly the meaning of intersection of events that you write

Comment: @Thomas, thanks for the clarification about notation.  I do not doubt that such notation is common as you say, while in my experience, standard set notation was more typical.  Duly noted.

Comment: I also wasn't sure that the comma means intersection. Just as a side, $P(C|A,B) = P(C|A \cap  B) = P(C|B \cap A)$, if I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes it is symmetric

Comment: See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property for an example of usage of the comma notation (in the definition section)